# PrimeFaces customize RowEditor in datatable

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a way to customize the rowEditor button? I mean if it is possible to change the image or add a text.
If it is not possible, is there a way to obtain the same behaviour with another control like button or link?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use CSS. The below example assumes that you want to apply it on all datatables/roweditors and have the desired image files in `/resources/images` folder.

```css
.ui-datatable .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/pencil.png']}");
}

.ui-datatable .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-check {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/check.png']}");
}

.ui-datatable .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-close {
    background-image: url("#{resource['images/close.png']}");
}
```

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997)

Comment: Thank you, and what if I want to add text label instead of an image?

Comment: You're welcome. Text is by default not supported by the component. You could use CSS `content` property, or use image with text, or create a custom renderer, or use JS/jQuery `text()`.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you want to use fa-icons from "Font Awesome" you can copy paste classes assigned to them from the font-awesome.css.

```
.ui-datatable table tbody tr td .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil 
{
   background: none !important;
   text-indent: initial;
   /* display: inline-block; */
   font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
   font-size: inherit;
   text-rendering: auto;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
   transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.ui-datatable table tbody tr td .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil:before {
   content: "\f044";
}
.ui-datatable table tbody tr td .ui-row-editor .ui-icon-pencil:hover {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: So what you effectively say is: use css ;-)